# How does sign_in_and_redirect in devise work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

```
if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

This method is present in the `facebook omniauth callbacks controller`. The problem that I am facing is that I do not get the user's phone number from facebook and thus `@user` is not a valid object (I have a `validation`). So, I want to redirect the user to another page where I can ask for the phone number.

How can I modify the sign_in_and_redirect @user to redirect me to that page and not the root url.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sign_in_and_redirect method [uses **after_sign_in_path_for** method to determine where to redirect the user after sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L236).

You can [easily customize your **after_sign_in_path_for** method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L184-L213) to check for the phone presence and either call super or redirect to the page where user can enter their phone number.