# Rails / Devise / Link to login page and pass it a redirect route to use after successful login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

How can I link to the devise login page and pass it a specific redirect_to route for a successful login. (the specific route has to change -> so overriding Devise RegistrationsController is not the proper option, or it has to be dynamic ...)

or

How can I add a redirect url to Devise `new_user_session_path()`

Comment: I don't think there is a way written into the API to pass a URL from `new_user_session_path`, but you can modify the `after_sign_in_path_for` hook with the logic you need. The links in this answer should put you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471885/how-does-sign-in-and-redirect-in-devise-work

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's not possible. You have to store the location in the controller, as described in my answer. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using `store_location_for(:user, jobs_path) unless user_signed_in?` in the index method

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        store_location_for(:user, jobs_path) unless user_signed_in?
        ...
    end
end
```